# Laravel HTML Facade conflict with Angular ng-submit

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I know that while using Angular's `ng-submit` will disable the default form action and use angular's function but the problem is when it is used with Laravel blade templating it somehow do not disable the function... So as below code, if i do something like this

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal signup-form', 'ng-submit' => 'updateProfile()')) !!}
```

and when I inspect the generated code, it gives me something like this

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.example.com:8000/profile/update" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal signup-form ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-submit="updateProfile()"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="8pNEBRXkUSfGUvSWfvFAmFPULLBO6kiet6LieC5B">
```

which when the submit button is triggered, it executes the form's action instead of calling the Angular's thus giving me an `MethodNotAllowedException`. But when I use manual coding like this

```
<form ng-submit="updateProfile()" class="form-horizontal signup-form">
```

everything works like a charm. I wonder if anyone knows any workaround to this issue can share their experience with me. i know that i can do manual code just for these section but again, I want to maintain consistency in the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you submit the form which generate by laravel form builder, it also calling the `updateProfile()` function and may be you don't prevent the default action of the event at the end, because of that form has a `action` so that page will submit to the `action`. If your form has no `action` then there is no way to submit the form as like your manual code, if you put a `action` to the manually coded form with the same `updateProfile()` it will submit the form to the action you provided.

to avoid that put `event.preventDefault();` inside the `updateProfile()` function.

```
$scope.updateProfile = function(event) {
    ...... 
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

and pass the event to the function as, `updateProfile($event)`

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal signup-form', 'ng-submit' => 'updateProfile($event)')) !!}
```